# Styling Radio Buttons

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I have this simple question at which I can find a direct answer in any place.
I need to include a radio button in my react native app and I've chosen kitten ui because it seems pretty complete. But the simplies and quickiest stuff seems 'convoluted' with this library. In the specific case I just want to change the color of the dot of the radio button, I don't want to style the entiere app, and I don't want to define mappings and stuff just to change a color (also because from the tutorial I read the mappings is for type of component, I want give more radio different colors).
The radio button offers the props text style but not the circle color, how can I configure this?
In the website there is an example where more radio have different colors, but it is the most usless kind of example, the ones with partial code and no reference to the full code, and there there is no informations of the styling.
Have someone some hint to style this component or how a style of a single component can be done quickly without define stuff at root level?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the color without using the function of the module?

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

Configuring a theme globally or customizing mappings it the only way to configure this. Also, you may use ThemeProvider from this library to override a theme for the specific case.